# .jstree() is not a function

Tags: webpack, jstree, webpack-encore, symfony5

I can't find a way to solve my problem. I want to use `jstree` library inside my `symfony5` app but I always get the `$(...).jstree() is not a function` or a `$.jstree is not defined` error in my javascript console.

`yarn watch` compile without error. I can see the `jstree` library code in my compiled js files. But it seems to be imported **after** the `$(function(){...});` function.

## my `index.js` file

```js
import '../../../css/accounting/account/index.scss';

import $ from 'jquery';
import 'jstree';

$(function () {
    console.log('account index spe file -- start');

    $("#accounts-jstree").jstree();

    console.log('account index spe file -- end');
});
```

## My `webpack.config.js` file

```js
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

// Manually configure the runtime environment if not already configured yet by the "encore" command.
// It's useful when you use tools that rely on webpack.config.js file.
if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    // only needed for CDN's or sub-directory deploy
    //.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')

    /*
     * ENTRY CONFIG
     *
     * Add 1 entry for each "page" of your app
     * (including one that's included on every page - e.g. "app")
     *
     * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.js)
     * and one CSS file (e.g. app.css) if your JavaScript imports CSS.
     */
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
    .addEntry('dashboard', './assets/js/core/organization/dashboard.js')
    .addEntry('operation_edit_create', './assets/js/accounting/operation/edit_create.js')
    .addEntry('bank_account_edit_create', './assets/js/accounting/bank_account/edit_create.js')
    .addEntry('account_index', './assets/js/accounting/account/index.js')
    //.addEntry('page1', './assets/js/page1.js')
    //.addEntry('page2', './assets/js/page2.js')

    // When enabled, Webpack "splits" your files into smaller pieces for greater optimization.
    .splitEntryChunks()

    // will require an extra script tag for runtime.js
    // but, you probably want this, unless you're building a single-page app
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
    // .disableSingleRuntimeChunk()
    /*
     * FEATURE CONFIG
     *
     * Enable & configure other features below. For a full
     * list of features, see:
     * https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html#adding-more-features
     */
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    // .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    // enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    // enables @babel/preset-env polyfills
    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
        config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
        config.corejs = 3;
    })

    // enables Sass/SCSS support
    .enableSassLoader()

    .copyFiles({
        from: './assets/img',
        to: 'img/[path][name].[hash:8].[ext]'
    })

    // uncomment if you use TypeScript
    //.enableTypeScriptLoader()

    // uncomment to get integrity="..." attributes on your script & link tags
    // requires WebpackEncoreBundle 1.4 or higher
    //.enableIntegrityHashes(Encore.isProduction())

    // uncomment if you're having problems with a jQuery plugin
    .autoProvidejQuery()

    // uncomment if you use API Platform Admin (composer req api-admin)
    //.enableReactPreset()
    //.addEntry('admin', './assets/js/admin.js')
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't ask me how but it I restart all of my docker containers and BOOM : It fell in order ...

:D

I'm interessested in your thoughts though....